# Typescript unable to infer the forwardRef return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a react HOC (Higher order component), which helps in merging props, for example, you might have a component which have some default properties, but you want the consumer of your component to be able to overwrite these properties, but not totally overwrite them, instead, patching some of them (this only happens in the case of objects, ex: think of the `style` prop):

```
function App(){
  return <NotFoundMessage buttonProps={{ style: { color: 'red' } }}>
}
function NotFoundMessage({ buttonProps }: { buttonProps: ButtonProps}){
  const ButtonM = withPropsMerge((props: ButtonProps) => <button {...props} />)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Hello there!</p>
      <ButtonM style={{ color: 'blue', background: 'red' }} $overwrite={buttonProps}>Return back home</ButtonM>
    </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Now, you don't have to know any of the above, the code of the `HOC` is pretty short, but it's giving me problems with typescript:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import { Optional } from 'utility-types'
import { mergeObjects } from 'mergerobjects'
import React, { FC, forwardRef } from 'react'

interface MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS extends object> {
  $overwrite?: Optional<ORIGINAL_PROPS>
  $preserve?: Optional<ORIGINAL_PROPS>
}

function withPropsMerge<ORIGINAL_PROPS extends object>(
  OriginalComponent: FC<ORIGINAL_PROPS>
): FC<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> {
  return forwardRef((props) => {
    const { $overwrite = {}, $preserve = {} } = props
    const injectedProps = mergeObjects($preserve, props, $overwrite)
    const originalPropsFiltered = _.omit(injectedProps as object, ['$overwrite', '$preserve'])
    return <OriginalComponent {...(originalPropsFiltered as ORIGINAL_PROPS)} />
  })
}

export default withPropsMerge
```

The error typescript is giving me is:

```
Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> & RefAttributes<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'FC<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>>'.
  Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
    Type 'WeakValidationMap<PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> & RefAttributes<unknown>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> | undefined'.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> & RefAttributes<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>>'.
        Type 'keyof ORIGINAL_PROPS | keyof MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.
          Type 'keyof ORIGINAL_PROPS' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.
            Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof PropsWithoutRef<ORIGINAL_PROPS & MergerProps<ORIGINAL_PROPS>> | keyof RefAttributes<unknown>'.ts(2322)
```

If I remove the `forwardRef()` everything works fine, but with `forwardRef()` it shows me the above error.